# Blow up of a Kähler manifold is Kähler

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, characteristic-classes, blowup, line-bundles

Let $X$ be a compact Kähler manifold and $x\in X$. Denoty $Bl_x X$ the blow-up of $X$ at $x$ and $E$ the exceptional divisor.

I want to see why $Bl_x X$ is Kähler.

I know the idea is to take the Kähler form $\omega$ of $X$ and a representative $\alpha$ of the Chern class $c_1(\mathcal O(-E))$ and combine them to the form
$\omega' = k \cdot p^* \omega + \alpha$ for $k>>0$.

My question is, how ensure that there is a right representative of $c_1(\mathcal O(-E))$ . I guess, we want to use that $c_1(\mathcal O(-E)|_E)$ has a positive representative and then extend it to the whole space $Bl_x X$ in a way, such that the extension represents $c_1(\mathcal O(-E))$. But why can I do this?

Comment: Have you looked at pp. 185-187 of Griffiths/Harris for an analogous discussion of positive line bundles on the blowup?

Comment: @TedShifrin: I did now. I see, they give an explicit construction of the metric,so this is the straight forward way. I was hoping to save some work by using the naturality of chern classes though =(

Comment: At a closer look, it seems that chern classes are somewhere hidden in the argument; at least they calculate the curvature of the chern connection

Comment: See also the reference here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2537880/k%c3%a4hler-form-on-the-blow-up-of-a-k%c3%a4hler-manifold?rq=1